# HP Laserjet 2100 printer doesn't print in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hplip, laserjet

I have an HP LaserJet 2100 printer. After having upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 I used localhost, but with the given configuration I cannot print the test page. In certain cases the red signal lamp  on the printer turns on and I have to cancel the print job.

With hplip I do not have the possibility to put lpt1 and I stop there.

Also when I setup the printer in the administration interface I cannot print. It exits with a error warning and the pdf blocks my printer.

But I am hoping for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a LaserJet 3200 (similar to your 2100 for printing). I didn't install HPLIP because it looked like a big software which I didn't need because I use it only for printing.

I tried many drivers (Footmatic, CUPS, Postscript, PCL5, PCL6) because the default one was having a pause between each page. In fact, some didn't even work. But the one that works great is the "Generic PCL Laser Printer". So to install:

- System Settings -> Printers
- Add printer
- Makes = "Generic" (instead of HP)
- Model = "PCL Laser"

About the Duplexer option at the end of the wizard (to print on both sides of the page), I didn't tick it because I don't use it (the 3200 doesn't have any automatic reversing document feeder so I would have to reverse the pages manually which is not practical).

Hope it helps

Comment: Also worked for a Hp2200 printer, can now print pdf without problems.